# javascript match first two letter in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a one string "United States United Kingdom United Nation" now I need to match the first two letter of every word.Above String will get the result 'Un' 'St' 'Un' 'Ki' 'Un' 'Na'.

How can i proceed this with the help of javascript\jquery.

Comment: What did you try so far?  Seems to me you should find the delimiter and just inspect the first two letters :-)

Comment: *Totally* unclear what you mean, and therefore lots of interpretations possible. Here is one: `match(/[USKN]./)` will match the Every Above String Words.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array#map`:

```
"United States United Kingdom United Nation".split(" ").map(function(element) {return element.substr(0,2)})
```

Using a regular Expression:

```
"United States United Kingdom United Nation".match(/\b\w\w/g)
```